# How to show messagebox in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, modal-dialog

I am new to PHP. I have to display a message box asking if new record is required or we can copy and modify an old record to the user while adding a new record. How can I do this? Please help.

Comment: What did you try so far? Messageboxes are usually in JavaScript

Comment: PHP is a server framework, are you looking for a javascript function to display to your users in the browser? (it's called confirm() )

Comment: I tried using modal forms and javascript but not able to get the result.

Comment: yes  Anders Bornholm,  have to display this to the user and get the option.

Comment: post the code you have used so far.Then only we can help you

Comment: I have to say that PHP _is not_ a framework. You can use pure javascript or some frontend javascript framework (like jquery-ui) to do it

Answer (score 3):

I usually use this for messageboxes:

```
function alert($string)
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $string . '");</script>';
}
```

Not the cleanest method, but usually works without problems.